# How to resize column on hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

What I am trying to do is,

column box is `100% width`, and when you hover it, I  want transition to left, and width of box column  about `60%`, and second block 20, only show when you hover a block.

My css and html are in this [**link**](http://www.bootply.com/TqS1Ece6Jw).

Let's say like this:

for example, if i have

```
<div main>
 <div left60%>
  <div right40%>
</div main>
```

While I am hovering main div, left div keep `60%` of width, and right `40%`.

Comment: give some more explanation about your problem

Comment: @Zubairsadiq First problem is that my hover transition doesnt work(smooth slide to the left) 2) right column(block 20) needs to have height ov child class(block)
3)third problem, i want this right column be hidden until i hover block

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ph9z54k/ try this its may helpful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3SYka/192/

Comment: left one must stay on 60%, while im hovering right block

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what it is you are trying to do but I think this might be close:
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cLne7hfy/1/)

I changed your box to:

```
.box{
    transition:2s;
  width:100%;
}
```

and added this to display the block20

```
.box:hover + .block20{
 display:block;
 }
```

I also told your block20 to `display:none` as you want it hidden before something happens

Comment: Ok transition now work but this box+block20 doesnt work, and when i'm hovering block20, box turn on 100% :/